# Sequelize does not generate timestamp manually

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My code is as shown below:

```
let time = db.sequelize.fn('NOW');
```

But somehow, it  shows 
`generated time is[object Object]` rather than time.
Is there anything missing to generate timestamp?